# How to view local drive properties

Tags: windows-8.1, reinstall, properties

I was using windows 8.1, suddenly something happens and some files goes corrupt ( may due to some virus). And now can't start my pc.
I know I can repair the files using windows DVD, but due to virus threat and some other minor issues I've decided to reinstall the window.
When I reinstalling the windows everything was going fine but the problem occurs when it prompt me to select *partition to install*. It shows all my three partition but not with the partition names (eg. C, D, E).
Now I've problem deciding with was my system partition (I don't want to format my other partition). There it shows **Total size** and **Free space** of the partition. So **is there any way to see the Local Drive properties** to help me decide which was my system partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple GUI method is when in the screen select partition to install,  you can press Shift-F10 to open command line. When in command line, type REGEDIT, then go to FILE -> OPEN, now you can view the drive properties by right clicking te drive or browse in entries drive